# Strange bound mismtatch using generics

Tags: java, generics

I have:

```
public abstract class HistorizableStatusEntity<S extends Status, 
       O extends IdentifiedEntity> extends IdentifiedEntity
```

with a concrete implementation:

```
public class OrderStatusHistory extends HistorizableStatusEntity<OrderStatus, Order>
```

Now there is:

```
public abstract class StatusableEntity<H extends HistorizableStatusEntity<S, IdentifiedEntity>, 
       S extends Status> extends IdentifiedEntity
```

with a concrete implementation:

```
public class Order extends StatusableEntity<OrderStatusHistory, OrderStatus>
```

The java compiler says regarding `Order`:

`Bound mismatch: The type OrderStatusHistory is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <H extends HistorizableStatusEntity<S,IdentifiedEntity>> of the type StatusableEntity<H,S>`

I do not understand this, because **OrderStatusHistory** extends `HistorizableStatusEntity<S,IdentifiedEntity>>`.

Any ideas? TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StatusableEntity` expects a type `H extends HistorizableStatusEntity<S, IdentifiedEntity>` whereas you provide `OrderStatusHistory` which expands to `HistorizableStatusEntity<OrderStatus, Order>`. As you see here, the right type is not matching what `StatusableEntity` expects (`Order` does not match `IdentifiedIdentity`).

Comment: Then use a boundary in `StatusableHistory`. In your snippet, you don't allow for subclasses of `IdentifiedIdentity`, you require a strict type matching

Comment: What do you mean by 'boundary'?

Comment: I meant *bound*, like `A extends B`

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem.